# how to fetch data from the server for each div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I use laravel and JQuery to display the html.

```
<div id="div1">0</div>
<div id="div2">0</div>
<div id="div3">0</div>
```

I need the `0` in the each div should be replaced by `time()` to display the current time in each div.

My Controller code looks like

```
class someController
{
  function get($divId=null)
  {
    return time();
  }
}
```

How could I do the **AJAX call** in Jquery to fetch the `time()` for each div.?
Could somebody please help?

Thanks

Comment: Unless there is a specific usecase for this you do not need to - and schould not - use ajax for that. Either display the time directly in your template with something like `echo date("Y/m/d H:i:s")` if you only need it to be printed once or use javascript to display a clock. Ajax puts unnessecary load on your server that is not needed here.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an JS interval.

```xml
<script>
$(function() {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
        let date = new Date();
        let hours = date.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
        let minutes = date.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
        let seconds = date.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');
        $('#div1').html(hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

[JavaScript Date Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)